# how to setup range_sensor_layer in local costmap

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am adding range_sensor_layer to local costmap of navigation stack (ROS Kinetic).
I followed the advise as mentioned in this post, [Parameters for the new range_sensor_layer](https://answers.ros.org/question/188027/parameters-for-the-new-range_sensor_layer/). However, I didn't manage to activate the range_sensor_layer in local costmap.

**//EDIT @ 11th Apr 19**

I setup as describe below.

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
plugins:
  - {name: obstacle_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
plugins:
  - {name: obstacle_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
map_type: costmap

transform_tolerance: 0.3

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.3

obstacle_layer:
  obstacle_range: 3.0
  raytrace_range: 2.5
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
  laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: hokuyo, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /myrobot/laser/scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

sonar_layer:
  ns: /arduino
  topics: ["/sonar1", "/sonar2", "/sonar3", "/sonar4", "/sonar5"]
  no_readings_timeout: 2.0
  clear_threshold: 0.05
  mark_threshold: 0.15
```

launch file:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
   <rosparam file="$(find myrobot)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
   <rosparam file="$(find myrobot)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
   <rosparam file="$(find myrobot)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"/>
   <rosparam file="$(find myrobot)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"/>
   <rosparam file="$(find myrobot)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    
   <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
   <param name="base_local_planner" value="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS"/>
</node>
```

And here is the output of roslaunch(timestamp is hidden), which range_sensor_layer is not initiated:

```
[ INFO] [--]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [--]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [--]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [--]: Resizing costmap to 2912 X 2496 at 0.020000 m/pix
[ INFO] [--]: Received a 2912 X 2496 map at 0.020000 m/pix
[ INFO] [--]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [--]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ INFO] [--]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [--]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [--]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [--]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ INFO] [--]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [--]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [--]: Sim period is set to 0.50
[ INFO] [--]: Received a 2912 X 2496 map @ 0.020 m/pix

[ INFO] [--]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [--]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [--]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
```

**//END OF EDIT**

I do know what I have missed. Please advice.
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320735/how-to-setup-range_sensor_layer-in-local-costmap/) by [simk0024](https://answers.ros.org/users/37383/simk0024/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess that your `local_costmap_params.yaml` is in the wrong namespace. Do a `rosparam dump` to see all the parameters.

The `plugins` should be loaded at `move_base/local_costmap/plugins` not `move_base/plugins`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simk0024](https://answers.ros.org/users/37383/simk0024/) on 2019-04-24**:
You are RIGHT! It's because of the indentation before the plugins.
By adding indent and make it like below will fix the issue of adding plugin

```
local_costmap:
    plugins:
      - {name: obstacle_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
      - {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
      - {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}

Log info:
    [ INFO] : local_costmap/sonar_layer: ALL as input_sensor_type given
    [ INFO] : RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /arduino/sonar1
    [ INFO] : RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /arduino/sonar2
    [ INFO] : RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /arduino/sonar3
    [ INFO] : RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /arduino/sonar4
    [ INFO] : RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /arduino/sonar5
```

However, range data still not reflected on the costmap, unlike pointcloud and laserscan.

**Comment by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on 2019-06-27**:
Hello @simk0024
I'm having the same problem, I can't reflect obstacles from range sensors on the costmap, did you find a solution?
Thanks

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-11-23**:
No solution till now?